# MySQL IF statement for ORDER BY clause issue

Tags: mysql

This is a bit of a strange one: I have the following MySQL Stored Proc (or function) and the majority can be ignored safely unless there is a need to understand the full picture.  The problem is the ORDER BY clause.

```
BEGIN 

    SELECT DISTINCT e.*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(in_latitude) ) * cos( radians( e.address_latitude ) )
       * cos( radians(e.address_longitude) - radians(in_longitude)) + sin(radians(in_latitude))
       * sin( radians(e.address_latitude)))) AS distanceFromUsersPostcode
    FROM event e
    INNER JOIN event_organiser eo on e.event_organiser_id = eo.id
    WHERE (e.event_name LIKE in_search OR e.address_town LIKE in_search OR e.address_county LIKE in_search OR eo.event_organiser_name LIKE in_search)
    AND e.start_date_time >= in_start_date
    AND e.start_date_time <= in_end_date
    AND e.enabled = true
    HAVING distanceFromUsersPostcode < in_maxDistanceFromUser
    /*
        * 1 *
        ORDER BY distanceFromUsersPostcode
        * 2 *
        ORDER BY IF(in_orderBy='LOCATION', CAST(distanceFromUsersPostcode AS DECIMAL), e.start_date_time) ASC;
    */
    ORDER BY 
        CASE in_orderBy
            WHEN 'LOCATION' THEN distanceFromUsersPostcode
            ELSE e.start_date_time
        END
    ASC;

END
```

Now the issue is this, the current uncommented ORDER BY clause seems to treat the DECIMAL value distanceFromUsersPostcode as a VARCHAR (or string) value.

It orders results in the form :

0.4, 101.9, 102.8, 11.1, 11.9

The same can be said if I used the variant labelled as * 2 *

However, if I revert to the original variant labelled as * 1 *, the results would be ordered as expected :

0.4, 11.1, 11.9, 101.9, 102.8

My guessing was that MySQL treated the distanceFromUsersPostcode variable as a VARCHAR if used inside the IF Function (* 2 *), hence my attempt to cast it to a DECIMAL.  This however, has no effect.

Can anybody shed any light on what is happening here?

The following acts as expected but isn't very elegant of course as it duplicates the entire query :

```
BEGIN 
    IF in_orderBy='LOCATION' THEN

        SELECT DISTINCT e.*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(in_latitude) ) * cos( radians( e.address_latitude ) )
            * cos( radians(e.address_longitude) - radians(in_longitude)) + sin(radians(in_latitude))
            * sin( radians(e.address_latitude)))) AS distanceFromUsersPostcode
        FROM event e
        INNER JOIN event_organiser eo on e.event_organiser_id = eo.id
        WHERE (e.event_name LIKE in_search OR e.address_town LIKE in_search OR e.address_county LIKE in_search OR eo.event_organiser_name LIKE in_search)
        AND e.start_date_time >= in_start_date
        AND e.start_date_time <= in_end_date
        AND e.enabled = true
        HAVING distanceFromUsersPostcode < in_maxDistanceFromUser
        ORDER BY distanceFromUsersPostcode;

    ELSE

        SELECT DISTINCT e.*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(in_latitude) ) * cos( radians( e.address_latitude ) )
            * cos( radians(e.address_longitude) - radians(in_longitude)) + sin(radians(in_latitude))
            * sin( radians(e.address_latitude)))) AS distanceFromUsersPostcode
        FROM event e
        INNER JOIN event_organiser eo on e.event_organiser_id = eo.id
        WHERE (e.event_name LIKE in_search OR e.address_town LIKE in_search OR e.address_county LIKE in_search OR eo.event_organiser_name LIKE in_search)
        AND e.start_date_time >= in_start_date
        AND e.start_date_time <= in_end_date
        AND e.enabled = true
        HAVING distanceFromUsersPostcode < in_maxDistanceFromUser
        ORDER BY e.start_date_time;

    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use different data types for sorting mysql will try to convert them to something convenient to be able to compare the values. In your particular case it will be conversion to string. So it makes no sense to convert `distanceFromUsersPostcode` to a number, because it will be converted back to string. You will need  to transform the string in a convenient format for number sorting. [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function will help you here.

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE in_orderBy
        WHEN 'LOCATION' THEN LPAD(CAST(distanceFromUsersPostcode as CHAR),6)
        ELSE e.start_date_time
    END
ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It didn't compile as you suggested and I altered it to LPAD(CAST(distanceFromUsersPostcode as CHAR),6, '0') to left pad with zeros.  However, it didn't work as intended unfortunately, just the same issue as before.

Comment: However, this got me thinking on the fact that MySQL is applying lexical sorting (so the two types match).  I managed to get the query working by using WHEN 'LOCATION' THEN (distanceFromUsersPostcode + 10000).  This has fixed the issue but leads me to a greater concern.  MySQL is now performing lexical sorting rather than sorting by number (or date) depending on which sort is supplied.  I've read elsewhere this can cause the query to run much slower.  If this is the case, I'd be happier duplicating the code segments as originally shown.  Less elegant but faster querying. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. This sorting requirement is unusual. Could you not rather think your request in an different way?